Fence not engineered for wind - suggestions on fix
This is part of a recently installed pool fence -- contractor has not yet been paid. For 75% of the fence, the fence is open. These panels were added for privacy on one end of the yard.
We had our first wind storm last night. While strong, the winds were not as strong as what we can get in this area.
Besides the flexing itself, the flexing has caused some of the anchors for the fence to fail and caused cracking in the block.
It appears to me that the contractor simply added panels to an existing fence style he's installed, probably countless times without issue. However, he clearly didn't consider wind in his design for privacy.
The contractor, via text, has indicated that he "will make some support posts to mount on the outside to stiffen it up," and will be out later today to have a look at it.
I can imagine installing angled posts to give extra support to prevent flexing. I'm not sure how I feel about the aesthetics of such a solution; I'm not currently opposed.
I'm wondering, though, if that's the best or even most reasonable solution to the problem.
Any suggestions?


If the anchors are failing, they're inadequate. Use better ones.
If the bases are failing, they're inadequate. Use better ones.
If the post are failing, or the panels, or ....
"Support posts" sound like a hacky solution. I'd want a properly robust fence. Do ask yourself whether a solid panel is reasonable in your environment, though. There are plenty of privacy panel options which don't act like quite so much like a schooner sail.

I'm open to suggestions on other privacy panel options.

That's a different question and probably doesn't solve your problem by itself. Any panel offering reasonable privacy will still catch some wind.

The big question is, does your contract call for a fence that can stand up to usual area winds?  If the contract only states that the fence will meet local code for pool security, then the contractor is actually going beyond what is expected and called for.
If you do not have a contract that states the fence will be able to sustain winds of at least "X", then the contractor has the clause of "acts of nature" on his side.  In that case, you should accept whatever solution the contractor offers. If they are willing to work with you to compromise on function and aesthetics consider yourself blessed.
